# Is it possible to clear the Netbeans output window from my application or temporarily disable all outputs?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.7, netbeans6.5

**Some background:**

I've created a Swing application which uses the [Substance LaF](https://substance.dev.java.net/see.html) (Thanks again, Kirill!)

Unfortunately Swing creates a panel somewhere outside the EDT thus leading to an exception message from Substance every time I start my application. By itself this exception is great, I already saved me from creating nasty multithread GUI bugs, but I often miss important outputs because the output window is already cluttered when my application does any real work.

The easiest way would be to patch the Substance source for my personal needs, but I'd rather leave it untouched. That's why I want to know...

1. Is it possible to clear the output window programmatically, either by calling a method from my application or something like a delayed Ant task?
2. Alternatively, can I temporarily disable any outputs from my application, including exceptions messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are trying to tweak the default behavior of the Output Window which is a part of the NetBeans IDE. You will need to use the relevant [NetBeans APIs](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/overview-summary.html). Please take a look at [OutputWriter](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-io/org/openide/windows/OutputWriter.html) and [OutputEvent](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-io/org/openide/windows/OutputEvent.html)

HTH.